# Como usar GITHUB en linux UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, git, github

estoy tratando de clonar mi repositorio en linux pero no me deja

```
suport for password was removed
```

tengo ya todo configurado, he agregado mis credenciales a `GIT`, generado `token en GITHUB` etc, pero nada, sigue saliendo el mismo error

**No sé porqué**

trata de loguearse con estas credenciales

```
username: miusuario
password for http://miusuario@github.com:
```

alguna forma de solucionar esto?

Comment: ¿Has [revisado](/q/492910/) [estas](/q/492536) [preguntas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68775869/)?

Comment: Usando tokens o llaves ssh. El soporte para autenticar con contraseña fue eliminado **en github**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En password debes colocar el token generado en github